# Cisco small business vpn firewall

Tags: cisco, vpn

I have the Cisco Small Business RV180W and I need to setup a VPN on it.

Do I have to buy a VPN client or can I use any VPN client?

I assume I can use any VPN client since all I am doing is generating a PSK and connecting to the IP with a user/pass/key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data sheet on that router it looks like it supports PPTP for remote vpn. Any PPTP client should work, Windows has one built in.